SFTP File Upload Failure
Starting off, I am very new to coding and servers and typically only edit existing code. Recently, I started a new WordPress site to launch an ecom business and I need to edit some of plugins to change the HTML in some of the generated emails (from Woocommerce). The plugin editor in WPsays "You need to make this file writable before you can save your changes." I followed instructions downloading FileZilla and enabling SFTP in the server settings. I can successfully login and view all the files. However, I cannot make changes to the majority of the files, notably the email templates I'm trying to edit. I cannot delete, overwrite, or edit file permissions for most of the files. Executing the order results in getting "open for write: received failure with description 'Failure'" error messages. I have double checked that I am connecting with sftp:// and I can make some edits, just not the ones I need. Any ideas on what I can try? Please remember, I am very inexperience and won't know a lot of terminology. Thanks in advance.

This is most likely a file permission issue and not at all related to WordPress. I suspect you are not logging in via SFTP as the same user who is the owner of the files you are trying to update.

@ScottM how would I go about finding if that's true? I followed WordPress's instructions exactly on how to setup a SFTP and copied the login information directly from the server dashboard.

I am not familiar with FileZilla. I believe you can view a file's permissions under the contextual menu when viewing the list of files on the remote server. That might show some clues as to what is going on. You might have better luck in getting help on another stack that deals with this kind of issue.
